# Why must I define a commutative operator twice?

Tags: c#

I wonder if I must define a commutative operator (like `*`) twice!

```
public static MyClass operator *(int i, MyClass m)
{
    return new MyClass(i * m.Value);
}

public static MyClass operator *(MyClass m, int i)
{
    return new MyClass(m.Value * i);
}
```

What's the logic behind this?

---

**Additional Descriptions:** Dear @Marc's answer about Vector and Matrix multiplication was good  ***if and only if we assume operand types are different !!! It's evident that we can define `*` operator only once to perform Vector or Matrix multiplication.*** So I think this is not the answer.

> @Marc: Order is sometimes important in operators.

Yes, but this is not equivalent with *Order is sometimes important in operands!* The above sentence may be used in case of using `+` operator before (or after) `*` operator that it will cause to different results. For example:

`0 + 2 * 2 != 0 * 2 + 2`

♦

Assume that we've defined `*` operator as:

```
public static MyClass operator *(MyClass m1, MyClass m2)
{
    return new MyClass(m1.Value * m2.Value /* or some other kind of multiplication */);
}
```

We *can not* define it again.

```
public static MyClass operator *(MyClass m2, MyClass m1) { ... }
```

If so, compiler would tell us that type `MyClass` already defines a member called 'op_Multiply' with the same parameter types.

Now, we can use this operator in two ways: `m1 * m2` or `m2 * m1` and they may have different results which depend on multiplication procedure.

Comment: Because order of operands matters?

Comment: @Mimi you are incorrectly assuming that multiplication is always commutative... it might be *in general*, and even *in your case*, but that doesn't mean it is ***always*** commutative.

Comment: As another trivial example; `+` is also sometimes interpreted as "append" (in the case of types acting like strings or collections; and I indeed won't get into the rights or wrongs of that) - but clearly "abc" + "def" does not commute.

Comment: You ask why you have to implement operators twice in some cases and then say that Marc's answer that answers your question isn't actual answer, because *in completely different cases*, you can't implement operators twice? Huh?

Comment: @svick Where did I say that?
Incidentally, as @Jon Skeet implicitly mentioned we can _and we should (if needed)_ implement operators twice in case of different types. What I'm insisting on is that we CAN NOT define an operator for the condition at which operands have the same type and because of this @Marc's example about Vector or Matrix multiplication is not accepted. (e.g. `Vector v1, v2; Vector v3 = v1 * v2;` Does this need to defining `*` operator twice?) *Please read additional descriptions carefully.* I believe that @zerkms's comment in case of different types of operands is the answer.

Answer (score 34):

Order is sometimes important in operators, the classic examples being subraction (`-`) and division (`/`). However, it can also apply to multiplication:

Consider, for example, that they are *vectors* - `x` is a (2×1) vector, and `y` is a (1×2) vector. If we interpret `*` as matrix multiplication, then `x * y` is a (2×2) vector, but `y * x` is a (1×1) vector.

As such, the C# compiler does not assume that binary operators are commutative, even if they *commonly* are (addition (`+`), multiplication (`*`), etc).

Comment: This behavior also exists for `+` operator. Can you bring me an example for it too please?

Comment: @Mimi the pseudo-operator on strings would be the most obvious; "abc" + "def" != "def" + "abc". For numbers etc? trickier as it generally *does* commute. But you could define anything you wanted to, really.

Comment: With all respect, I disagree with you about the above example, because "abc" & "def" have the same type and there is a unique way to define an operator for. But I all agree with you about ability of defining flexible operators. (Although it can make use of operators complicated.)

Answer (score 16):

You don't have to do that - you only need to do that if you want to be able to write:

```
MyClass x = ...;

MyClass y = x * 5;
MyClass z = 5 * x;
```

If you only want *one* of the bottom two lines to be valid, you can delete the other operator overload.

Basically, the C# language doesn't assume that multiplication is commutative even in terms of the *types* involved.

Answer (score 3):

For commutative operations, you don't need to implement the entire thing twice, you can reference the initial operator. For example:

```
    public static Point operator *(Point p, float scalar)
    {
        return new Point(
                scalar * p.mTuple[0],
                scalar * p.mTuple[1],
                scalar * p.mTuple[2]
            );
    }

    public static Point operator *(float scalar, Point p)
    {
        return p * scalar;
    }
```

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass {
    private int i;
    public MyClass(int x)  {
        i=x;
    }
    public static MyClass  operator+(MyClass a , MyClass  b)  {
        return new MyClass(a.i+b.i);
    }
    public static implicit operator MyClass(int  a) {
        return new MyClass(a);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MyClass a , b ,c ;
        a=new MyClass(2);
        b=a+4;
        c=4+a;
        Console.WriteLine("B = {0}, C = {1}",b,c);

    }
```

There you go, all you have to do is have the compiler turn int into MyClass instance and then use the MyClass + MyClass method.