# Two operator overloading methods needed or not?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Is there a way to tell C# that these two are the same implementation and only needed once?

```
public static Matrix4 operator *(Transform u, Matrix4 v)
{
    return u.Result * v;
}

public static Matrix4 operator *(Matrix4 u, Transform v)
{
    return u* v.Result;
}
```

Comment: yes, needed! this is kind of a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385937/why-must-i-define-a-commutative-operator-twice ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax that would let you declare to C# that your operators are commutative. It does not matter much when the implementation is simple, because you are not actually writing the same code multiple times. For more complex implementations, the actual logic can be placed in a shared private method, like this:

```
public static Matrix4 operator *(Transform u, Matrix4 v) {
    return Mult(u, v);
}
public static Matrix4 operator *(Matrix4 u, Transform v) {
    return Mult(u, v);
}
// The actual implementation goes here
private static Matrix4 Mult(Matrix4 u, Transform v) {
    return u* v.Result;
}
```

This approach lets you avoid repeating the logic of the implementation, so that if you need to correct anything, you have to make a change in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

yes they are needed.one of them is called if the left operand is `Transform` and the right operand is `Matrix`.Other one is called if the left operand is `Matrix` and right operand is `Transform`.